# Send XML Request and receive XML Response from other server using Ajax or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I have to send an Xml to other server(an web service of a travel company) and receive response in Xml
An example of xml request is:
.......................................................................................................................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Request RequestType="getCountryRequest">
        <AuditInfo>
            <RequestId>
                001
            </RequestId>
            <RequestUser>
                user
            </RequestUser>
            <RequestPass>
                password
            </RequestPass>
            <RequestTime>
                2012-09-04T18:00:46
            </RequestTime>
            <RequestLang>
                RO
            </RequestLang>
        </AuditInfo>
        <RequestDetails>
            <getCityRequest CountryCode="RO"/>  
        </RequestDetails>
    </Request>
```

And the response must look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Response ResponseType="getCityResponse">   
    <AuditInfo>     
        <ResponseId>
            12940524
        </ResponseId>     
        <RequestId>
            12949986
        </RequestId>     
        <ResponseTime>
            2012-09-04T18:10:02
        </ResponseTime>   
    </AuditInfo>   
    <ResponseDetails>     
        <getCityResponse>       
            <City>         
                <CountryCode>
                    ENG
                </CountryCode>         
                <CityCode>
                    ENG
                </CityCode>         
                <CityName>
                    Madrid
                </CityName> 
            </City>
        </getCityResponse>   
    </ResponseDetails> 
</Response>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

It should be something close to this (using jQuery):

```
    var query = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request RequestType="getCountryRequest"><AuditInfo><RequestId>001</RequestId>'+
            '<RequestUser>user</RequestUser><RequestPass>password</RequestPass><RequestTime>2012-09-04T18:00:46</RequestTime><RequestLang>'+
             'RO</RequestLang></AuditInfo><RequestDetails><getCityRequest CountryCode="RO"/></RequestDetails></Request>';

    $.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_URL_HERE',
    data: query, 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (xmlResponse){
        xmlResponse = $.parseXML( xmlResponse ),
        $xml = $( xmlResponse ),
        $title = $xml.find( "ResponseId" ); //to get the ResponseId for example
    },
});
```

Comment: There is a conflict at: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
I think the issue is <? and ?>

Comment: Now appears an error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://paradis.touringit.ro/server_xml/server.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://all-in-one.wdigital.md' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: That is what i was worried about, the api server seems to not allow cross domain ajax queries, so you need to send the request using cUrl or other server side scripts.

Comment: Can you please look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514573/how-to-send-request-and-receive-response-in-xml-using-jquery-and-ajax