# How To Send Request And Receive Response In XML Using Jquery And Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, soap

I have a xml file called AmaSend.xml. So , I have to send this xml file as a request and I want to get Response from another xml file. Then I tried like below. But , always I got

> ReferenceError: xml is not defined

How can I fix this and send request and receive response ??

Here is AmaAll.php file

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

                        var sourceOffice = 'Value1';
                        var originator = 'Value2';
                        var referenceIdentifier = 'Value3';
                        var organizationId = 'Value4';
                        var binaryData = 'Value5';

                        var originatorTypeCode = 'Value6';
                        var referenceQualifier = 'Value7';
                        var dataLength = '8';
                        var dataType = 'E';

                        console.log(sourceOffice);

                        var query = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Security_Authenticate><userIdentifier><originIdentification><sourceOffice>Value1</sourceOffice>/originIdentification><originatorTypeCode>U</originatorTypeCode><originator>Value2</originator></userIdentifier>'+
            '<dutyCode><dutyCodeDetails><referenceQualifier>DUT</referenceQualifier><referenceIdentifier>SU</referenceIdentifier></dutyCodeDetails></dutyCode>'+
             '<systemDetails><organizationDetails><organizationId>NMC-I</organizationId></organizationDetails></systemDetails>'+
             '<passwordInfo><dataLength>8</dataLength><dataType>E</dataType><binaryData>Value3</binaryData></passwordInfo></Security_Authenticate>';

                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'AmaRes.xml',
                        data: query, 
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success : function (xmlResponse){
                            var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlResponse = $.parseXML( xmlResponse ),
                            $xml = $( xmlResponse ),
                            $title = $xml.find( "statusCode" ); //to get the ResponseId for example
                            alert($(xml).find("statusCode")[0].attr("id"));
                        },
                    });             

                    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is AmaSend.xml file ( Request ).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Security_Authenticate>
  <userIdentifier>
    <originIdentification>
      <sourceOffice>Value1</sourceOffice>
    </originIdentification>
    <originatorTypeCode>Value2</originatorTypeCode>
    <originator>Value3</originator>
  </userIdentifier>
  <dutyCode>
    <dutyCodeDetails>
      <referenceQualifier>Value4</referenceQualifier>
      <referenceIdentifier>Value5</referenceIdentifier>
    </dutyCodeDetails>
  </dutyCode>
  <systemDetails>
    <organizationDetails>
      <organizationId>Value6</organizationId>
    </organizationDetails>
  </systemDetails>
  <passwordInfo>
    <dataLength>Value7</dataLength>
    <dataType>Value8</dataType>
    <binaryData>Value9</binaryData>
  </passwordInfo>
 </Security_Authenticate>
```

Here is AmaRes.xml ( Response )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awss="http://xml.amadeus.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <awss:Session>
      <awss:SessionId>Value1</awss:SessionId>
      <awss:SequenceNumber>Value2</awss:SequenceNumber>
      <awss:SecurityToken>Value3</awss:SecurityToken>
    </awss:Session>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Security_AuthenticateReply xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/VLSSLR_06_1_1A">
      <processStatus>
        <statusCode>Value4</statusCode>
      </processStatus>
    </Security_AuthenticateReply>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: alert($(xml). should possibly be alert($xml....)

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan - Still , I can't send request or receive response. That's what I want to Fix.

Comment: Start by fixing this error, delete this question - ask a NEW question with the NEW error if you cannot find out how to fix the NEW error

Comment: This is a waste of processing `xmlResponse = $.parseXML( xmlResponse ),
                            $xml = $( xmlResponse ),`